# Rails create multiple tokens for same record (multiple coupons for one offer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, multiple-records

so here is what I am trying to do:
when the user is creating a special offer, he writes down how many coupons there should be. Each of these coupons is stored in the database with a unique code.

Example:

He wants to sell 100 coupons for "Dinner offer". When he creates the "Dinner offer" and types in, that he wants 100 coupons, these 100 coupons should be generated.
How am I supposed to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell which parts of this you're asking for help on. Are you not sure how to generate unique coupon codes, not sure how to model it, not sure how to create multiple records at a time? I'll try to give a general answer of what I'd do if I were building this, and maybe that will be helpful to you.

I'd create two models, `Offer` and `Coupon`:

```
rails g model offer title:string user:references
rails g model coupon offer:references code:uuid
```

I don't know if you're using mysql or postgresql. I think uuid will only work on postgresql. If you're using mysql I guess make the code column a string instead. Or better yet, switch to postgresql. ;)

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :coupons
end

class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :coupon

  before_create -> { self.code = SecureRandom.uuid }
end
```

I would index the database on your `code` column and make it unique, and disallow `code` from being `nil`. Might as well make both columns disallow `nil`, I'm a big believer in doing that wherever possible in the database:

```
class CreateCoupons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :coupons do |t|
      t.references :offer, index: true, null: false
      t.uuid :code, null: false
    end

    add_index :coupons, :code, unique: true
  end
end
```

Normally when you create a coupon you'd just do:

```
offer.coupons.create!
```

And it would generate the code for you in the `before_create` hook. But since you want to create like 100 of them at once, the simple way would be:

```
100.times { offer.coupons.create! }
```

But that's going to be kind of inefficient. I don't know of a way to get Rails to do an efficient INSERT of many records, so we're going to do it manually:

```
objs = []
100.times do
  objs.push "(#{offer.id}, '#{SecureRandom.uuid}', '#{Time.now}', '#{Time.now}')"
end

Coupon.connection.execute("INSERT INTO coupons (offer_id, code, created_at, updated_at) VALUES #{objs.join(", ")}")
```

If there's a more Railsy way of doing this, someone please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have the model **Offer** with a **has_many :coupons** relationship, and your **Coupon** model has the **belongs_to :offer** relationship.

If so, then you can do

```
amount_of_coupons = params[:amount_of_coupons]
offer = Offer.create params.permit(:attr1, :attr2)
offer.coupons.create Array.new(amount_of_coupons).map{ {code: (0...64).map{ (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join} }
```

that would create 100 coupons connected to your offer, with a randomly generated 64 character code.

Comment: The amount_of_coupons is selected by the user creating the offer.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it will be better to make the coupon code generated by the Coupon itself which can make the code length the same across the whole system.

```
amount_of_coupons = 100

amount_of_coupons.times do
    offer.coupons.create({:attr => value})
end

class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :code
    before_create :set_coupon_code

    def set_coupon_code
        self.code = SecureRandom.hex(32) unless self.code
    end
end
```

Comment: The amount_of_coupons is selected by the user creating the offer.

Comment: @figdig amount_of_coupons just a parameter, you can assigned it from params.